# SQL Case and Cross apply

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pull values from and XML string that is stored in an ntext field.

With this code I'm getting the correct results but there is another case where the root(ListA) XML is different (ListB). Can i use Case/If or anything else to take in account the other root

```
SELECT 
 List_Name.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as List_Name
FROM Lists
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(content AS XML)) AS A(B) 
CROSS APPLY A.B.nodes('//ListA')  AS Lists(List_Name)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) You should store `XML` values into a `XML` column not into a `ntext`.

2) I'm not sure if this is what you need but you could loot at this example:

```
SELECT  z.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS li_element_text,
        z.XmlCol.value('(@type)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS li_type_attribute
FROM 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<ol><li type="disc">A1</li><li type="square">A2</li></ol>')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<ul><li type="circle">B1</li></ul>')
) x(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY x.XmlCol.nodes('/*') y(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY y.XmlCol.nodes('li') z(XmlCol)
```

Output:

```
li_element_text li_type_attribute
--------------- -----------------
A1              disc
A2              square
B1              circle
```